# How to apply default WordPress header but only elementor footer on all pages In WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have developed my custom footer using elementor but I have my default theme header. I have applied the elementor footer to all website but Now it is not showing my header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to add only elementor footer and the default theme header, Just go to the footer.php and paste the shortcode in the file.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('SHORT_CODE'); ?>
```

Comment: E.g. `<?php echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="1573"]'); ?>`